# Closing AdMob interstitial destroys the current activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, android-manifest

When I close the AdMob interstitial, the current activity gets destroyed. I created the activity and the interstitial like this:

```
public class testActivity extends SherlockActivity{

public static final String IMG = null;
Context con;
public Bitmap currentbmp;
private String imgfile;
public int replacecolor;
public ImageView showcolor;
private AdView mAdView;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;   
public ImageView imageview, imageview1, imageview2;

public testActivity()
{
    replacecolor = 0xffff0000;
    imgfile = null;
    currentbmp = null;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.floodfill);
    imgfile = getIntent().getStringExtra(IMG); 
    con = this;
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewad);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
        mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_intertestial_id));
        requestNewInterstitial();

    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.floodfill);
    imageview1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorpal);
    showcolor = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.showcolor);
    showcolor.setBackgroundColor(replacecolor);

    try
    {
        imageview.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(imgfile), null));
        imageview1.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("CATIMAGE/color.png"), null));
        imageview1.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {

            Bitmap pmap;
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent)
            {
                try
                {
                    //requestNewInterstitial();
                    Point point = new Point();
                    point.x = (int)motionevent.getX();
                    point.y = (int)motionevent.getY();
                    ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorpal);
                    imageview2.buildDrawingCache();
                    pmap = imageview2.getDrawingCache();
                    replacecolor = pmap.getPixel(point.x, point.y);
                    showcolor.setBackgroundColor(replacecolor);

                }
                catch (Exception exception) { }
                return true;
            }



        });


    } catch (Exception exception) { }


    imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        Bitmap bmap;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                Point point = new Point();
                point.x = (int)event.getX();
                point.y = (int)event.getY();
                ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.floodfill);
                if (bmap == null)
                {
                    imageview2.buildDrawingCache();
                    bmap = imageview2.getDrawingCache();
                }
                int i = bmap.getPixel(point.x, point.y);
                int j = replacecolor;
                (new TheTask(bmap, point, i, j, imageview2)).execute(new Void[0]);
            //  requestNewInterstitial();

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResume()
{  
    Log.i("onResume", "onResume");
    super.onResume();

}
@Override
public void onPause()
{  
    Log.i("OnPause", "onPause");
    super.onPause();    
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("Ondestroy", "destroyed");
    super.onDestroy();
}




private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
          @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
            //  FloodFillActivity.this.onPause();
                mInterstitial.show();
            }
        }
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
            //  FloodFillActivity.this.onResume();
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");


            }
    });
}
```

}

and this my Androidmanifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.testapp.testActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

LogCat output:

[LogCat output pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Oy5u.jpg)

[LogCat output pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipAoV.jpg)

Why the activity getting destroyed? I tried all the proposed solutions and get no solution, knowing that I'm using eclipse and I use this method in many activities and that never caused any problem... but this!! I really have no idea.

Any help, advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance.

Comment: can u try this android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|fontScale|mcc|locale|screenLayout|layoutDirection"

Comment: see if you have latest google play services sdk.. see this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/OK28TOutigo

Comment: Thank u for your attention @AmodGokhale. I already have the latest google play services and unfortunately tried the android:configChanges.... and it doesn't work :/

Comment: interesting..would recommend to update above thread your example so that they can take a look

Comment: Thank you @AmodGokhale, seems like my question doesn't appear!! I still got no answers...